# How to make table not offside when scrolling?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm developing web page with `php` that show table, the problem is when the I'm scrolling the table, the table cover my header.If I'm using fixed header, footer and sidebar.

Please help to make the table not cover the header when scrolling.

This is my `php + html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/blended_layout.css">
    <title>Early Warning System</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fixedheader">
        <h2>Early Warning System</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="fixedsidebar">
        Hello World!
    </div>

    <div id="maincontent">
        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <th>Site ID Actual</th>
            <th>Site Name Actual</th>
            <th>Regional</th>
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Month OA</th>
            <th>OA Date</th>
            <th>Harga Sewa</th>
            <th>Durasi Sewa</th>
            <th>Tanggal Mulai</th>
            <th>Tanggal Berakhir</th>
            <th>Opsi</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        //include file koneksi ke database
        include('koneksi.php');

        //query ke database dgn SELECT table siswa diurutkan berdasarkan NIS paling besar
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM on_air") or die(mysql_error());

        //cek, apakah hasil query di atas mendapatkan hasil atau tidak (data kosong atau tidak)
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)
        {
            echo '<tr><td colspan="6">Tidak ada data!</td></tr>';
        } else
        {
            $no = 1;
            while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data['site_id_actual'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data['site_name_actual'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data['regional'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data['area'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data['type_of_opex'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data['oa_date'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data['harga_sewa'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data['durasi_sewa'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data['tgl_mulai'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data['tgl_berakhir'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id='.$data['site_id_actual'].'">Edit</a> / <a href="hapus.php?id='.$data['site_id_actual'].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Yakin?\')">Hapus</a></td>';
                echo '</tr>';

                $no++;
            }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    </div>

    <div id="fixedfooter">
        <h5 align="right">&#169; Copyright Telkomsel 2015</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is my css :

```
body {
margin:80px 80px 100px 100px;}
div#fixedheader {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:99%;
color:#CCC;
background:#333;
padding:30px;}

div#fixedfooter {
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
width:99%;
color:#CCC;
background:#333;
padding:10px;}

div#fixedsidebar {
position : fixed;
left : 0px;
width : 15%;
height : 90%;
color : #CCC;
background : #333;
padding : 10px;}

div#maincontent {
position : relative;
left : 15%;
width : 84%;
height : 90%;
color : #000;
background : #FFF;
padding : 10px;}
```

Comment: add `z-index:1024;` to your header, then it will be always on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `z-index` in your `div#fixedheader` div.

```
div#fixedheader {
    background: #333;
    color: #ccc;
    left: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 99%;
    z-index: 1; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: why do you use `none repeat scroll 0 0;` when theres no image?